# SQL Change Rank based on any value in group of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not looking for the answer as much as what to search for as I think this is possible. I have a query where the result can be as such:

```
| ID | CODE | RANK |
```

I want to base rank off of the code so my I get these results

```
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 1 |
| 2 | A | 1 |
| 2 | C | 1 |
| 3 | B | 2 |
| 3 | C | 2 |
| 4 | C | 3 |
```

Basically, based on the group of IDs, if any of the CODEs = a certain value I want to adjust the rank so then I can order by rank first and then other columns. Never sure how to phrase things in SQL.

I tried 
`CASE WHEN CODE  = 'A' THEN 1 WHEN CODE = 'B' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END rank
ORDER BY rank DESC`

But I want to keep the ids together, I don't want them broken apart, I was thinking of doing all ranks the same based on the highest if I can't solve it another way?

Thoughts of a SQL function to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `MIN() OVER()` analytic function to get the minimum rank value per group, and just order by that;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, code, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN code='A' THEN 1 WHEN code='B' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY id) rank
FROM mytable 
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY rank, id, code
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea4aa/1).

Comment: `Partition`. I knew something like that existed, but just didn't know what it was called.

Comment: Makes my query a bit slower but I'm slogging through a pretty hefty query with a ton of rows. I cache it for a day anyway, so were good. Thanks a ton.